# wso2 identity server oauth userinfo only returns sub

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have set up SP in wso2 Identity server and was able to get access_token in auth2 using playground. 
Ref : https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/OAuth+2.0+with+WSO2+Playground

Then I accessed userinfo endpoint like :

```
curl -k -H "Authorization: Bearer 603b0a91-0354-3b64-90e9-0eb1fdd8f162" https://localhost:9443/oauth2/userinfo?schema=openid
```

I always get JSON :

```
{"sub":"admin@carbon.super"}
```

But there should also be other properties like first name,last name, email ... etc by default. How do I configure server to return all these information?

P.S tried IS 5.1 and 5.2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenId Connect with wso2 returns only sub claim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34889038/openid-connect-with-wso2-returns-only-sub-claim)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems the logic to return claims by UserInfo Endpoint for scope openid is only the intersection of claims configure at OIDC file and claims configured in SP level are returned. Based on this logic I was able to solve this problem by following steps.

1. WSO2 IS default openid scope is bound to set of predefined claims. You can configure this using oidc file found in /_system/config/oidc as in following screenshot.
   [image]
2. Say for eg. if you want to get user's email address using openId scope by default it should comes with userInfo endpoint because "email" scheme is set-up by default (see above screenshot)
3. According to [default claims](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Configuring+Claim+Dialects)

   - http://wso2.org/claims - Default dialect for WSO2 Carbon
   - http://wso2.org/oidc/claim - Default dialect for OpenID Connect

Look at values of **Claim Uri** and **Mapped Attribute** of the email claim at http://wso2.org/oidc/claim dialect 
[image]

4. Now you need to add correct http://wso2.org/claims claim which is mapped to the email claim in http://wso2.org/oidc/claim to the SP configuration. You can find it using same **Mapped Attribute**.
   i.e. For this example there is a same "Email" claim in http://wso2.org/claims.
   [image]
5. Add "Email" claim in http://wso2.org/claims to the SP configuration
   [image]

Now for the request

```
curl -k -H "Authorization: Bearer 8b2805a7-5b74-33ee-84df-2a8c53a16f6c" https://localhost:9443/oauth2/userinfo?schema=openid
```

you would get response

```
{"sub":"admin@carbon.super","email":"admin@wso2.com"}
```

Comment: I have all the configurations as you mentioned and I am trying to login using facebook as an IDP  but I am still getting only sub in the response of userinfo endpoint whereas I am getting email, given_name, and family_name for google and linked in. What could be the issue?

We are using WSO2 IS 5.3.0

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are facing seems to be reported in [1]. Issue is originally reported for IS 5.1.0 and there were some inconsistencies in 5.2.0 release. According to the jira this will be fixed in 5.3.0 release, which is scheduled to release soon.

[1] https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-4250