# wso2 identity server after token refresh userinfo returns wrong results and only sub

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have set up a WSO Identity server v5.3.0 and got OAuth2 authentication working against it. I have set it up with Google as a federated authenticator.

After following the instructions on [wso2 identity server oauth userinfo only returns sub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41281292/wso2-identity-server-oauth-userinfo-only-returns-sub), I get my real email-address when querying the userinfo endpoint:

```
{
  "email": “<my-real-email-adress>“,
  "sub": "<my-real-email-adress>"
}
```

But after the accessToken is refresh-et I get

```
{
  "sub": "<my-real-email-adress>@carbon.super"
}
```

So `email` is gone, and the `sub` is not correct any more.

How do I set it up so I can still use the userinfo endpoint after the token is refreshed?

It works after token-refresh if I turn off the federated authentication, and instead use the default authentication build-in in WSO2

Edit: Here is a screen shot of my service provider configuration

[Screenshot of service provider configuraion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKYv8.png)

Comment: can you share a screenshot of your service provider configurations? specially the claim configs and the local and outbound authentication sections of the service provider?

Comment: Added to the original post